# Jenkins: Uploading File to Server via HTTP POST using Jenkins Request Plugin

Tags: http, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, content-type

I am trying to upload a Softwarefile from Jenkins to a server via Pipeline. The Server API needs the following information:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
 
boundary= 'boundary'

body = 
--'boundary'
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=origFilename

????
--'boundary'--
```

Unfortunately the HTTP Request Plugin does not support Content-Type "multipart/form-data" (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)

I tried to just leave out the content type (since I have the options to leave it out or giving a false one) and got 415 error code. Since I'm trying to send a .txt file and knowing that the server accepts text-files (I successfully uploaded one via Postman) I think this may results from the content-type.

Current Code:

```
httpRequest  httpMode: 'POST', url: "https:<host>.com/", requestBody: '--' + "<boundary>" + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";' + 'filename="JenkinsDemo.txt"' + '???' + "<boundary>" + '--'
```

Is there any other way to get the file uploaded to the server? Or do you have a solution for using the plugin?

Comment: Tried [HTTP Post](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http-post/) or maybe  [Publish over SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/) ?

Comment: HTTP Post could be working, but I´m not able to find documentation to know how to use it... Do you smth about it? Publish over SSH ist not suitable in my situation. Thx for suggestions!

Comment: I am only aware of it from a user's undetailed request to install "HTTP plugin" (HTTP Request, not POST). I'd suggest emailing the Dev (see source [pom.xml](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-post-plugin/blob/e1647b9f98dff32c54d4331a57fd06b7b5cc21cf/pom.xml#L39) for email) and asking him - where is the documentation and how to raise an issue against it. TBH, I don't even know how that made it into the plugin lib; no tests, no documentation, not updated in 6 years, using jdk 1.6 and Jenkins-plugin:1.480. Looser standards back then?

Comment: I wrote him an e-mail, but I also figured out that I´m able to use CURL to make it run. Unfortunately I´ve got another problem with the CURL-Request now, which I mentioned in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629304/jenkins-using-variable-in-shell-script-curl-request)
Thank´s for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `httpRequest` plugin *does* do file uploads. I have previously used it.

Set `uploadFile` as the path to your file for uploading and, if necessary, set `contentType` to your chosen content type.

Comment: is this meant as a comment?

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use this for myself...

The `httpRequest` plugin can upload files via `multipart/form-data`.

- First, you need to specify the file to upload with `uploadFile`
- Then, define the attribute name of your upload inside the form data to send with `multipartName`
- Last, switch your HTTP command with `httpMode`

At the end your setup can look like this:

```
def response = httpRequest url: 'yourhost.com', httpMode: 'POST', uploadFile: 'text.txt', multipartName: 'file'
echo "${response}"
```

If needed, you can set your content type with `contentType`

See: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/