# Jenkins: Using variable in Shell Script / CURL Request

Tags: variables, jenkins, curl, https, sh

I save a number out of a response from an earlier HTTP Request into a variable. In the CURL Request I need to insert this number into the URL, but somehow It doesn´t get recognized as a variable. It just gets sorted out which is why the URL is wrong and I get a 400 Error.

```
script{

// first httpRequest where I get the number from
def response = httpRequest httpMode: 'POST', url:"https://myServer.com", contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8', requestBody: 'myBody'

def props = readJSON text: response.content

def num = props.id[0]       //num stores the number now

sh(Script: curl "https://myServer.com/$num/files" -i -X POST -H Content-Type:multipart/form-data -F file=@JenkinsDemo.txt
}
```

The console output shows me that the sh tries to reach https://myServer.com//files , so it leaves out the variable.

I also tried to put the whole URL into a variable and refer in curl but it doesn´t get recognized as well.
Of course I tried several typing options like ${num}, '$num' etc...

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I also get the message "message":"The given url contains malicious characters" , probably because of the '$'

Another weird thing: If I type ${props.id[0]} instead of ${num} (which doesn´t make any difference because they hold the same number) the message changes to
"/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline Test@tmp/durable-153a0829/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline Test@tmp/durable-153a0829/script.sh: Bad substitution"

Comment: Are you sure `num` does not hold an empty string? Try printing `num` to check what value is stored in `num`.

Comment: yes num is filled with the correct number e.g. 379192
I also can print it within the shell script but it doesn´t work in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. the curl request needs to be surrounded by double quotation marks.

```
sh("curl https....")
```

The double quotation marks enable the possibility to use the variables defined in groovy script. Without them it just gets interpreted as java String.